# Google Authorization: Error 400: redirect_url_mismatch

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0

I am working on my company domain to connect any amount, n, of google sheets to a python script to scrape data and create another spreadsheet. The company does not allow direct sharing of google sheets to their gcp environment.

So I have gone the route of Oauth to accomplish this. I found the code below on stack (forgive me for losing the link) and adjusted it to my needs.

The problem is I cannot get authenticated as I keep getting the Error 400: redirect_url_mismatch - The redirect URl in the request , http://localhost:8080/, does not match the ones authorized.

The authorized url is: `http://localhost:8080' and this is the same call I make in the code (this same url is authorized in the javascript origins as well).

I think the problem is that the trailing `/` is not captured in the authorized URls on the gcp environment, but I am told by that team that the trailing `/` is not supported (URl will not save because of the `/` so it was omitted).

I have spent a full day on this and am not certain what is the issue or how to work around.

```
from oauth2client.tools import run_flow, argparser
from oauth2client.file import Storage
rscope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
CLIENT_ID = 'MY CLIENT ID'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'MY CLIENT SECRET'
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id=CLIENT_ID,
                           client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
                           scope=rscope,
                           redirect_url='http://localhost:8080')
storage = Storage('mycredentials.csv')
credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, argparser.parse_args([]))
import requests
import gspread, ast
from oauth2client.client import AccessTokenCredentials
data = {
    'refresh_token' : credentials.refresh_token,
    'client_id' : credentials.client_id,
    'client_secret' : credentials.client_secret,
    'grant_type' : 'refresh_token',
}
r = requests.post('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', data = data)
try :
    credentials.access_token = ast.literal_eval(r.text)['access_token']
except Exception: 
    pass;
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Just to be clear; when you say `authorized URL` are you talking about the authorized domiains in the OAuth consent screen, or the redirect URI set up when you create the client credentials?

Comment: Thank you for asking the clarifying question. I am referring to the authorized domains in the OAuth consent screen.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*You need to set `https://localhost:8080` as your redirect URL in GCP.*

#### More Information:

When you set up your Client credentials in GCP, you need to set up the redirect URL for the credentials. This is the callback URL for your client to go back to after a grant has been given - which is not the same as the authorized domains in the OAuth consent screen.

#### Steps:

1. In the GCP console for your Project, go to `APIs & Services > Credentials` and click `+ CREATE CREDENTIALS > OAuth Client ID`.
2. Click `Web Application` and give your client credentials a name.
3. Under `Authorized redirect URIs`, enter `https://localhost:8080`
4. Create your credentials.

Now, you will need to download these new credentials and use them with your application. It is also possible you may need to change the protocol listed in your app to use `https` as in:

```py
    # ...
    redirect_url='https://localhost:8080')
```

Comment: I have not yet done that, so it is worth a try. Just to be clear the redirect url should be ```https``` as opposed to ```http```? I have only seen it as the latter.

Comment: Both should work but it's good practice to do  over https given you're working with auth flow

Comment: After much fiddling and configuring adding this to the redirect urls is not working.
I am still getting the authorization error. Is there a specific url to use for redirect?